# Splitting of Sodium Line in weak magnetic field

Tags: atomic-physics, spectroscopy

Someone asked me two question which are

> "On application of weak magnetic field the Sodium line arising due to the transition $^2 P_{3/2} \to ^2 S_{1/2}$ will split ideally into."

and

> "The transition $3^2 P_{3/2} \to 3^2 S_{1/2}$ leading to $D_2$ line of sodium in a magnetic field greater than the internal magnetic field will split into."

**In both question it is asked to find number of components in which magnetic field will split**.

*Are both the above two questions are same and giving same answer because I know the answer of first question*?

Comment: Look up the Zeeman splitting for those sodium lines.

Comment: No, the starting state has different value of $J$ in the two cases, leading to more splitting int he second case

Comment: I edited my problem now what will be the explanation? @DanDan0101

Comment: As I said: http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/quantum/sodzee.html#c2.